# Data set request on domestic violence and the health and economic impacts it has

Tags: data-request, data.gov, research, crime

I am a student and have an assignment on the health and economic impacts of domestic violence. I need a "data set" on domestic violence to run a descriptive analysis for any correlation if any between these variables. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Resources from DoJ includes:
https://www.bjs.gov/index.cfm?ty=tp&tid=235
https://www.bjs.gov/index.cfm?iid=245&ty=dcdetail

Answer (score 1):

Virginia Department of Health has many datasets on domestic violence: [Domestic Violence Fatality Review Resources](http://www.vdh.virginia.gov/medical-examiner/fatality-review-surveillance-programs-reports/domestic-violence-fatality-review/resources/).
You'll have to do the legwork of pulling the data out of the PDFs, but its all there for you to use.